# How can i change the textcolor of my timepicker and datepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, timepicker

Currently I am working on one of my first applications. In this application I have a `TimePicker` and a `DatePicker`. My current `Activity` has a dark background. Now I want a white textcolor in my `TimePicker`/`DatePicker`.

In my layout I have defined my pickers:

```
<DatePicker android:id="@+id/dpDateOfValue" android:calendarViewShown="false" />
<TimePicker android:id="@+id/tpTimeOfValue" />
```

The solution should work on 2.3 - 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<style name="MyHolo" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">

        ...

        <item name="android:editTextColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

to set TimePicker text color for API >= 11

Answer (score 1):

For DatePicker I use this code:

```
public static void setDatePickerTextColor(DatePicker dp, int color) {
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) dp.getChildAt(0);
    if (l != null) {
        l = (LinearLayout) l.getChildAt(0);
        if (l != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) l.getChildAt(i);
                if (np != null) {
                    setNumberPickerTextColor(np, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker, int color) {
    final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            try {
                Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                ((Paint) selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
                ((EditText) child).setTextColor(color);
                numberPicker.invalidate();
                return true;
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Log.w("NumberPickerTextColor", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.w("NumberPickerTextColor", e);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.w("NumberPickerTextColor", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Although, it was tested only on Lollipop.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this using Coding, try following:

```
DatePicker your_picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpDateOfValue);
EditText edittext = (EditText) your_picker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("datepicker_input", "id",  "android"));

edittext.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: [Once See This](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/1287p4zckr/changing-text-color-font-for-datepicker-widget)

Comment: This solution not work for me. The edittext object is always null. Is there a mistacke in the getIdentifier function?