# Change TimePicker font color in android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I need my TimePicker font color to be white. I tried approach, described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227884/how-can-i-change-the-textcolor-of-my-timepicker-and-datepicker) question, but it doesn't work for me. So any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969513/how-can-i-override-timepicker-to-change-text-color

Comment: http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.fr/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969513/how-can-i-override-timepicker-to-change-text-color

Answer (score 2):

Create a style :

```
 <style name="MyBase.TimePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Then use it in yout TimePicker like this :

```
<TimePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tpScheduleTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:theme="@style/MyBase.TimePicker"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add style like this:

```
    <style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

and add this in your code:

```
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),R.style.TimePickerTheme, (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```